# Watson Conversation Logs by Date

Tags: python, python-2.7, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson

I wanted to know if there is a way to pull Watson conversation logs for a specific time period using Watson Python SDK? Also is there a way to avoid the pagination added at the end of the logs? I want to pull all the logs for a given time period. Below is the code I am currently using which pulls logs for a specific workspace:

```
import json
import watson_developer_cloud

conversation = watson_developer_cloud.ConversationV1(
    username='xxxxxxxxxx',
    password- 'xxxxxxxx',
    version='2017-05-26'
)

response = conversation.list_logs(
    workspace_id = 'xxxxxxx'
)

js = json.dumps(response,indent=2)

with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(response, outfile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the [Official documentation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/filter-reference.html#filter-query-reference), you can use the `filter` parameter to list logs and have a lot of options to use.

Filter: `filter/string` A cacheable parameter that limits the results to those matching the specified filter. For more information, see Filter query reference.

> The timestamp of the response is earlier than
>   2016-11-01T04:00:00.000Z.
>
> ```
> response_timestamp<2016-11-01T04:00:00.000Z
> ```

So you need to replace with your `response_timestamp`:

```
list_logs(workspace_id, sort=None, filter=paste here, page_limit=None, cursor=None)
```

- See more about the filter parameter using [Logs - Watson Conversation](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/filter-reference.html#filter-query-reference).
- See the Official API Reference [about Logs using Python](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?python#get_logs).