# How should the Chatbot conversation raw data excel csv look like?

Tags: csv, export, chatbot, watson-conversation

How should the Chatbot conversation raw data excel csv look like?

Now I am building a Chatbot with IBM Watsons. The client would want the chatbot conversation raw data export in excel/csv format. As the conversation is very long, How should we get the most appropriate format for the Chatbot conversation raw data csv?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, I guess you should use `Logs/` examples on the API Reference for base what you CSV file gonna have, for example: `inputText, outputText, conversation_id, dateConversation, intents, entities, context, workspace_id, etc.`

In this example using [Python](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/python.html?python#logs) that will return these data (you can also use another language that has HTTP request support):

*List logs:*

```
list_logs(self, workspace_id, sort=None, filter=None, page_limit=None, cursor=None)
```

*Request:*

```
import json
import watson_developer_cloud

conversation = watson_developer_cloud.ConversationV1(
    username='{username}',
    password='{password}',
    version='2018-02-16'
)

response = conversation.list_logs(
    workspace_id = '9978a49e-ea89-4493-b33d-82298d3db20d'
)

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

**Obs.:** Take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648791/watson-conversation-logs-by-date) saving inside one `txt` file the conversation Logs, you can also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3345418/7133482) to use the same logic to save in one `csv` file.

Obs.: Nowadays Watson conversation changed the name for Watson Assistant.

- Official [Watson Conversation API Reference](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1) (cURL, Node, Java, Python examples)